# costmap begineer question[update]

Tags: ros, navigation, laser, costmap, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using the move_base, there are some topics of local_costmap

and Im following a tutorial using grid cell to display the cost on map,

but I find nothing as shown below with the rqt_graph

What should I do with?

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Best,
Evoe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201822/costmap-begineer-question%5Bupdate%5D/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2015-01-27**:
Are you wanting to mark a costmap with your own costs or do you just want to use the costmap to track obstacles and inflation layers?

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-28**:
I want to track obstacles and inflation layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz you've used a Gridcells Display to try and visualise your costmap. The Grid cells display subscribes to nav_msgs::Gridcells, whereas your costmaps are published as nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid. Change your rviz configuration to use the Map Display type for your costmaps. The Map display type subscribe to nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2015-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on 2015-01-29**:
But I found that the type show is GridCells

$ rostopic type /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles
nav_msgs/GridCells

I am following this tutorials
(http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack)

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2015-01-29**:
I've not used Gridcells, but viewed costmaps using the costmap topic, in your case it should be /move_base/local_costmap/costmap. Do you have this topic?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank for the answering. I found the main problems.

1. the package move_base doesnt support 32bit computer, after I use another computer to run, it works.
2. one of the param (min_obstacles_height) has to be 0.

Now I can see the costmap, Thank you very much.

---

Originally posted by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) with karma: 41 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1